# Trying to copy a RFID tag, and thats as far as I am able to come

Tags: rfid, mifare, cloning

I cannot copy the whole RFID tag, some lines are not cloned properly. Also, empty spaces "-" have been replaced with an "F" if Im not wrong. [This is where Im at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1utr.jpg) (B:ORIGINAL; A:COPY)

I already managed to copy the whole bloc 0, however Im struggling with a few lines in the other blocs. The mifare tool cannot apply them to my RFID tag. I needed the extended-std function to be able to view a few blocs of the original tag. So regular methods like using arduino won't work, because they cannot access the original tag's blocs. They're seen as "empty bloc" or just unreadable